# Upload Image With idhttp indy9 delphi7

Tags: indy

i want to upload image to telegram server with post but i get read timeout error or 415 unsupported media type.

telegram says:
"
Photo to send. You can either pass a file_id as String to resend a photo that is already on the Telegram servers, or upload a new photo using multipart/form-data.
"

what is wrong?

```
var
IDUser : String;
Stream: TStringStream;
Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
msg : WideString;
LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
Src , boundry : string;
begin
  API := edtAPI.Text;
  IDUser := Edit1.Text;
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      //Params.AddFile('File1', 'C:\test.txt','image/png');
      Params.AddFormField('chat_id',IDUser);
      Params.AddFile('File1', 'E:\image.png','image/png');
      //Data.CopyFrom(Params,0);
      //Params.AddFormField(' test',',');
      try
        msg := '/sendPhoto';
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
        //IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
        IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 30000;
        IdHTTP1.IOHandler:=LHandler;
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
        IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := true;
        IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';

        idhttp1.Request.SetHeaders;
        memoResponse.Text :=idhttp1.Request.RawHeaders.Text;
        memoRequest.Text := BaseUrl + API + msg;
        IdHTTP1.Post(BaseUrl + API + msg, Params,Stream);
      except
        on E: Exception do
          showmessage('Error encountered during POST: ' + E.Message+ ': '
          + intToStr(IdHTTP1.Response.ResponseCode))
      end;
      ShowMessage(Stream.DataString);
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
```

sorry for poor english.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this without seeing the actual API documentation. Can you provide a link? The only issues I see in your code is that you are setting `Request.ContentType` manually (`Post()` handles that for you), and you are calling `Request.SetHeaders()` directly (don't do that). If you want to log what `TIdHTTP` send, you can attach a `TIdLog...` component to `TIdHTTP`, such as `TIdLogEvent` or `TIdLogStream`.

Comment: hi . this link : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

Comment: When calling `Params.AddFile()`, you need to use `'photo'` instead of `'File1'` as the field name.

Comment: Remy Lebeau thank you very much. my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  Stream: TStringStream;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  msg : WideString;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
  IDUser : string;
begin
  API := edtAPI.Text;
  IDUser := Edit1.Text;
  msg := '/sendPhoto';
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      Params.AddFile('photo', 'E:\image.jpg','');
      Params.AddFormField('chat_id',IDUser);
      Params.AddFormField('caption',UTF8Encode('ÇÑÓÇá ÊÕæíÑ åã ÏÑÓÊ ÔÏ'));
      try
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
        //IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 300000;
        IdHTTP1.IOHandler:=LHandler;
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
        IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := true;
        //idhttp1.Request.ContentType := Params.RequestContentType;
        memoRequest.Text := BaseUrl + API + msg;
        IdHTTP1.Post(BaseUrl + API + msg, Params, Stream);
      except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('Error encountered during POST: ' + E.Message);
      end;
      memoResponse.Text := Stream.DataString;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remy Lebeau thank you very much. my problem is solved.